# How do I set up server side end points for a backbone.js app using sinatra and codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js, sinatra, codeigniter-2

I want to create single page applications using backbone.js and want to deliver these apps to my client using php and ruby.

I like both Sinatra and codeigniter. How would I go about setting up server side endpoints for my application? Right now I am developing a cloud computing billing calculator.

Where do I create models and collections? On the client and server side?

Comment: Sorry @Amit but I feel this question very generic and imposible to offer a proper and concrete answer.

Comment: It is generic because I am trying to grasp the situation and not solve a specific problem yet.

Answer (score 4):

Backbone is a client-side JavaScript solution offering models, views and collections (of models) that help you manage your data and views on the client-side. Backbone, by default, can populate its client-side models with data from a server using REST APIs.

You can build your server-side models however you want, but (by default) they need to be accessed through a simple REST API like this using the model functions, sync(), fetch() and save():

- create → POST   /collection
- read → GET   /collection[/id]
- update → PUT   /collection/id
- delete → DELETE   /collection/id

More information can be found here:

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync

Here's an overview of how to create a REST API with code igniter:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Here an overview of how to create a REST API with symfony:

http://di-side.com/di-side/services/web-solutions/rest-webservice-symfony/

Comment: so do I also have to mirror my client models on the server side?

Comment: @AmitErandole, essentially, yes. Currently, without using [some crazy hacks with node.js](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/) you can't just use your backbone models on the server.